# React Native Glowing Background Accent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I am trying to build an app kinda like this in react-native and I want to create that green accent at the top left corner, I have been trying to use SVGs with less opacity but for some reason, they become solid when I use them with react-native-svg, How can I make this?

[image: app screen]

Comment: You can use [Linear Gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient)

Comment: Posting the code with your attempt, even if it is completely broken, will allow other users to help you much more than they can without any actual code to look at. Please post your attempt & we can help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Using react-native-svg module, please use this. I hope it'll help you.

```
<Svg height="150" width="300">
  <Defs>
    <RadialGradient
      id="grad-8"
      cx="10%"   //Set the radius corner by x
      cy="10%"   //Set the radius corner by y
      r="70%"    //Set the gradient radius
    >
        <Stop 
          offset="0" 
          stopColor="#fff"   //Set the Gradient color(From)
          stopOpacity="0" 
        />
        <Stop 
          offset="1" 
          stopColor="#00f"   //Set the Gradient color(To)
        />
    </RadialGradient>
  </Defs>
  <Rect
    x="10"
    y="10"
    width="290"
    height="130"
    fill="url(#grad-8)"
  />
</Svg>
```

for more info, see the npm [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg).
and for demo expo, [click here](https://snack.expo.io/@msand/react-native-svg-example).

Comment: It is giving an error, Can't find variable RadialGradient

Comment: For that: Add `import {LinearGradient} from 'react-native-svg';`